# Search text in browser using c#

Tags: c#, regex

In c# I am using web client class to open the html. In that html i there are particular IPs. I want to search my local machine IP

```
   WebClient wbclint = new WebClient();
       value1 = wbclint.DownloadString("foo.html");
                        Console.WriteLine("testing");
                        Console.ReadKey(true);
```

So using this web client how to capture particual ip?

Answer (score 0):

use a regular expression to search the string, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228595%28v=vs.80%29.aspx here's an example to do something very similar using regular expressions in c#; to validate phone numbers.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Test
{
    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        if (args == null || args.Length == 0)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException ("Specify the URI of the resource to retrieve.");
        }

        var client = new WebClient ();
        var s = client.DownloadString (args[0]);

        // var data = client.OpenRead(args[0]);
        // var reader = new StreamReader(data);
        // var s = reader.ReadToEnd();

        var myIP = "100.100.100.100";
        var ipFound = s.Contains(myIP);

        Console.WriteLine("Is my IP in the web page?: {0}", ipFound );

        data.Close ();
        reader.Close ();
    }
}
```